# CSS and blog entries not showing in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

Ive been following this quick tutorial on setting up a basic blog in Django

http://arunrocks.com/recreating-the-building-a-blog-in-django-screencast/

this is the source code for it

https://github.com/arocks/qblog

there is also a video, my problem is at the 9.23 mark when the home.html page has been setup in templates to show the published blog posts while using base.html which is from bootstrap blog and Im also using that CSS and JS.

https://youtu.be/7rgph8en0Jc?t=9m23s

my problem is that when I run it now it doesn't show my any of my blog posts (I made several entries in admin already), it just shows the contents of base.html and nothing from home.html and also Im not seeing any CSS at all, its all just plain html text.

this is all my code here

https://github.com/davejonesbkk/myblog/tree/master/myblog

my only difference is that I have my templates and static folders inside my app folder 'blog' as I had seen elsewhere that this is the recommended folder structure. I did try moving both the folders up to the top level like in the tutorial but then when I runserver I get an error saying it can't find the files in templates.

Even though Im still learning this is not my first time using Django and Ive done several other projects before so I do have some knowledge in this area and I simply can't figure out why my home.html and the CSS doesn't work...

EDIT: added in correct Github link for tutorial source code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see `{% load static_files %}` in either `base.html`or `home.html`.

Also try changing `{% extends 'base.html' %}` to `{% extends 'templates/base.html %}`.  Your folder structure is different than what I use, so this may not help.

Comment: OK thanks, you were right about the staticfiles, Ive added that back now, it still looks the same and also when I make the 'extends' changes I get this error now                                                                                     TemplateDoesNotExist at /
templates/base.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.9.6
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
templates/base.html

Comment: the weird thing is its loading in the contents of base.html just fine and home.html is in the same folder...

Comment: I set up my `templates` directory top level under the project root; at the same level as my app directories.  Within that  `templates` directory, I have directories for each app and their templates within.  So I use `{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}`.

Comment: I think the problem is your `blog.css` link in `base.html`.  Try using django tags like `<link href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`.

Comment: thanks, that was it so the css is working now but its just showing the content of base.html but nothing from home.html or any of my posts, I will work on it further anyway